# Como capturar o evento click de uma row do dbgrid?

Tags: delphi

Gostaria de saber como faço para pegar o evento `click` de uma linha qualquer, retornada do BD no `GridView`.

Por exemplo, o `GridView` me mostra 3 linhas, quero clicar numa dessas linhas e executar uma determinada ação.

Comment: mas que ação deseja executar?

Comment: Supondo que as linhas retornadas fora: 
'id nome    idade 
1  joao           23 
2  josé           34 
3  maria        43 '
ai quero clicar no josé e pegar seu id para comparar num case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procure o evento `onClick` na palheta de Object Inspector.

Ao clicar no Grid ele já seta no registro do banco de dados, então você pode capturar o `id` e fazer o teste.

```
procedure Tfrm.DBGri1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case  TQuery.fieldbyname('id').asInteger of
  1:;
  2:;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Supondo que as linhas retornadas foram:

Comment: Supondo que as linhas retornadas fora:
id nome     idade
1  joao           23
2  josé           34
3  maria        43
ai quero clicar no josé e pegar seu id para comparar num case

Comment: esta ligado em que componente de banco de dados?

Comment: Num TQuery com um DataSource

Comment: por que ao clicar no Grid ele ja seta no registro do banco de dados, entao voce pode capturar o id e fazer o teste.

Comment: vou editar minha resposta

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra alternativa é usar o evento [`OnCellClick`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DBGrids_TCustomDBGrid_OnCellClick.html), ele é disparado quando o usuário clica em alguma célula da grade.

Veja um exemplo:

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1CellClick(Column: TColumn);
var
  ID: integer;
begin
  ID := DBGrid1.Fields[0].AsInteger; // Pega a o valor da primeira coluna selecionada

  case ID of
    1: ShowMessage('João');
    2: ShowMessage('José');
    3: ShowMessage('Maria');
  else
    ShowMessage('Nome desconhecido!');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Sim, mas esse metodo seria mais indicado se você aproveitar o Column: TColumn  se não tanto faz.

Comment: @GabrielLocalhost Sim, por exemplo se você quiser obter o valor selecionado independentemente da coluna: `ShowMessage(Column.Field.AsString)`.

Comment: isso mesmo, custumo usar assim mesmo